# How to put content in box and make it responsive?

Tags: html, css

i have this simple problem that i can't solve, it seems like something simple is missing. I have a code here and i want to have many bubbles with similar content, but my text gets all disorted,because i use weird margin numbers to make it fit for that specific resolution.

I feel like i am missing an important syntax, that can make this whole thing easier, so my goal is to fit the images on both sides, and put text in centre to make the bubble responsive.

Thank you for any help :)

Here is my code snippet

```css
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0;    
}

.bubble-content {
width: 800px;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}

.MaleLogo {
width: 25%;
float: left;
vertical-align: top;
margin: -180px 0px 0px 40px;
}

.Bubble {
width=100%;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 200px;
}

.Obrazky-skoly {
width: 25%;
border-radius: 30px;
border: 4px #E2EEE7 solid;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
float: right;
margin: -150px 30px 0px 0px;
}

.MalyNadpis {
font-size: 40px;
margin: 5px auto;
color: #F6EAEA;
text-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.MalyPopis {
text-align: center;
width: 35%;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 5px auto;
color: #F6EAEA;

}

.Chemie {
background-color: #67C170;
border: 10px #4DD672 solid;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px 0px 30px 0px 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble-content">
    <div class="Chemie Bubble">
        <p class="MalyNadpis"> Title  </p>
        <p class="MalyPopis"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis bibendum o saeoni fea  gea geasdgea gfea nso einaos safse fda </p>
        <img class="MaleLogo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Logo Chemie">
        <img class="Obrazky-skoly" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting fixed widths on the bubble so it can never shrink or grow. You need the bubble to be able to get bigger or smaller as the screen grows. I changed your Bubble style to be 100% of the width of the element it is inside. I also changed it to display as flexbox and wrapped your text in bubble inside a div so it can scale wit the flexbox.

```
<div class="bubble-content">
<div class="Chemie Bubble">
    <img class="MaleLogo" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="Logo Chemie">
    <div class="Bubble__Text">
       <p class="MalyNadpis"> Title  </p>
       <p class="MalyPopis"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis bibendum o saeoni fea  gea geasdgea gfea nso einaos safse fda </p>
    </div>

    <img class="Obrazky-skoly" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50">
</div>
```

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin:0;    
}

.bubble-content {
width: 100%
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
}
.Chemie {
background-color: #67C170;
border: 10px #4DD672 solid;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 50px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), 0px 0px 30px     0px 
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.Bubble {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 200px;
display: flex;
padding: 0 80px;
}
.Bubble img {
  align-self: center
}
.Bubble__Text {
  margin: 0 25px;
}
.Obrazky-skoly {
border-radius: 30px;
border: 4px #E2EEE7 solid;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);

}
.MalyNadpis {
font-size: 40px;
margin: 5px auto;
color: #F6EAEA;
text-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.MalyPopis {
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
margin: 5px auto;
color: #F6EAEA;
}
```